# Open journal system does not show article xml view problem

Tags: php, css, wordpress, ojs

i have installed ojs 3.1.1 and create joural and article etc, when i view the front of this article shows only pdf download form but i needed also xml view, Ojs 3 contained xml views plugin of article but xml view is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@inam, have you uploaded your XML files as galleys? OJS doesn't generate XML-based articles by itself -- you'll have to do it yourself and upload the resulting XML into OJS (or integrate OJS with an external tool like Open Typesetting Stack).

Comment: yes i have uploaded now xml files in galleys but when i click on xml link it url show 504 error , mean its link is not open further. where xml view show. kindly help.